# Edit number field for all rows. Start from integer xxx, then +1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a field "TransactionID", which is datatype number. This field starts from 0, and increases by +1 for each new row. In some cases, there is a need to make this field start from a specific number. Is there a way to go in and update each rows, to start from number xxx, and increase by 1?

```
Set number xxx
Start from lowest transactionID
Set first rows transactionID to number xxx
Next rows transactionID xxx+1
Next rows transactionID to xxx+2
```

It's probably like 12 rows that needs to be updated.

This is the whole createtable scripted:

```
    USE [RetailChannelDatabase]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE]    Script Date: 06.12.2016 12:39:36 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE](
    [AMOUNTTOACCOUNT] [numeric](32, 16) NOT NULL,
    [BATCHID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [BATCHTERMINALID] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [BUSINESSDATE] [date] NOT NULL,
    [CHANNEL] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [CHANNELREFERENCEID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [COMMENT] [nvarchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [COSTAMOUNT] [numeric](32, 16) NOT NULL,
    [COUNTER] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CREATEDOFFLINE] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CREATEDONPOSTERMINAL] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [CURRENCY] [nvarchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [CUSTACCOUNT] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [CUSTDISCAMOUNT] [numeric](32, 16) NOT NULL,
    [CUSTPURCHASEORDER] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [DESCRIPTION] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [DISCAMOUNT] [numeric](32, 16) NOT NULL,
    [DLVMODE] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [ENTRYSTATUS] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EXCHRATE] [numeric](32, 16) NOT NULL,
    [FISCALDOCUMENTID] [nvarchar](80) NOT NULL,
    [FISCALSERIALID] [nvarchar](80) NOT NULL,
    [GROSSAMOUNT] [numeric](32, 16) NOT NULL,
    [INCLUDEDINSTATISTICS] [int] NOT NULL,
    [INCOMEEXPENSEAMOUNT] [numeric](32, 16) NOT NULL,
    [INFOCODEDISCGROUP] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [INVENTLOCATIONID] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [INVENTSITEID] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [INVOICECOMMENT] [nvarchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [ITEMSPOSTED] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LOGISTICSPOSTALADDRESS] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [LOYALTYCARDID] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [LOYALTYDISCAMOUNT_RU] [numeric](32, 16) NOT NULL,
    [NETAMOUNT] [numeric](32, 16) NOT NULL,
    [NUMBEROFINVOICES] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NUMBEROFITEMLINES] [numeric](32, 16) NOT NULL,
    [NUMBEROFITEMS] [numeric](32, 16) NOT NULL,
    [NUMBEROFPAYMENTLINES] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OPENDRAWER] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PAYMENTAMOUNT] [numeric](32, 16) NOT NULL,
    [POSTASSHIPMENT] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RECEIPTDATEREQUESTED] [date] NOT NULL,
    [RECEIPTEMAIL] [nvarchar](80) NOT NULL,
    [RECEIPTID] [nvarchar](18) NOT NULL,
    [REFUNDRECEIPTID] [nvarchar](18) NOT NULL,
    [REPLICATED] [int] NOT NULL,
    [REPLICATIONCOUNTERFROMORIGIN] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RETRIEVEDFROMRECEIPTID] [nvarchar](18) NOT NULL,
    [ROUNDEDAMOUNT] [numeric](32, 16) NOT NULL,
    [SALEISRETURNSALE] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SALESINVOICEAMOUNT] [numeric](32, 16) NOT NULL,
    [SALESORDERAMOUNT] [numeric](32, 16) NOT NULL,
    [SALESORDERID] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [SALESPAYMENTDIFFERENCE] [numeric](32, 16) NOT NULL,
    [SHIFT] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [SHIFTDATE] [date] NOT NULL,
    [SHIPPINGDATEREQUESTED] [date] NOT NULL,
    [SKIPAGGREGATION] [int] NOT NULL,
    [STAFF] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [STATEMENTCODE] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [STORE] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [TERMINAL] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [TIMEWHENTOTALPRESSED] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TIMEWHENTRANSCLOSED] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TOACCOUNT] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TOTALDISCAMOUNT] [numeric](32, 16) NOT NULL,
    [TOTALMANUALDISCOUNTAMOUNT] [numeric](32, 16) NOT NULL,
    [TOTALMANUALDISCOUNTPERCENTAGE] [numeric](32, 16) NOT NULL,
    [TRANSACTIONID] [nvarchar](44) NOT NULL,
    [TRANSCODE] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TRANSDATE] [date] NOT NULL,
    [TRANSTABLEID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TRANSTIME] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TYPE] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WRONGSHIFT] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CREATEDDATETIME] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [MODIFIEDDATETIME] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DATAAREAID] [nvarchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [ROWVERSION] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [I_-1558077251_-1679712867] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [STORE] ASC,
    [TERMINAL] ASC,
    [TRANSACTIONID] ASC,
    [CHANNEL] ASC,
    [DATAAREAID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [UI_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_REPLICATIONCOUNTERFROMORIGIN] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [REPLICATIONCOUNTERFROMORIGIN] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_AMOUNTTOACCOUNT]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [AMOUNTTOACCOUNT]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_BATCHID]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [BATCHID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_BATCHTERMINALID]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [BATCHTERMINALID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_BUSINESSDATE]  DEFAULT ('1900-01-01') FOR [BUSINESSDATE]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_CHANNEL]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [CHANNEL]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_CHANNELREFERENCEID]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [CHANNELREFERENCEID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_COMMENT]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [COMMENT]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_COSTAMOUNT]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [COSTAMOUNT]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_COUNTER]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [COUNTER]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_CREATEDOFFLINE]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [CREATEDOFFLINE]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_CREATEDONPOSTERMINAL]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [CREATEDONPOSTERMINAL]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_CURRENCY]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [CURRENCY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_CUSTACCOUNT]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [CUSTACCOUNT]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_CUSTDISCAMOUNT]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [CUSTDISCAMOUNT]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_CUSTPURCHASEORDER]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [CUSTPURCHASEORDER]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_DESCRIPTION]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [DESCRIPTION]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_DISCAMOUNT]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [DISCAMOUNT]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_DLVMODE]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [DLVMODE]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_ENTRYSTATUS]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [ENTRYSTATUS]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_EXCHRATE]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [EXCHRATE]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_FISCALDOCUMENTID]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [FISCALDOCUMENTID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_FISCALSERIALID]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [FISCALSERIALID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_GROSSAMOUNT]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [GROSSAMOUNT]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_INCLUDEDINSTATISTICS]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [INCLUDEDINSTATISTICS]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_INCOMEEXPENSEAMOUNT]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [INCOMEEXPENSEAMOUNT]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_INFOCODEDISCGROUP]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [INFOCODEDISCGROUP]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_INVENTLOCATIONID]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [INVENTLOCATIONID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_INVENTSITEID]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [INVENTSITEID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_INVOICECOMMENT]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [INVOICECOMMENT]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_ITEMSPOSTED]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [ITEMSPOSTED]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_LOGISTICSPOSTALADDRESS]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [LOGISTICSPOSTALADDRESS]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_LOYALTYCARDID]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [LOYALTYCARDID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_LOYALTYDISCAMOUNT_RU]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [LOYALTYDISCAMOUNT_RU]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_NETAMOUNT]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [NETAMOUNT]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_NUMBEROFINVOICES]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [NUMBEROFINVOICES]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_NUMBEROFITEMLINES]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [NUMBEROFITEMLINES]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_NUMBEROFITEMS]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [NUMBEROFITEMS]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_NUMBEROFPAYMENTLINES]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [NUMBEROFPAYMENTLINES]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_OPENDRAWER]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [OPENDRAWER]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_PAYMENTAMOUNT]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [PAYMENTAMOUNT]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_POSTASSHIPMENT]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [POSTASSHIPMENT]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_RECEIPTDATEREQUESTED]  DEFAULT ('1900-01-01') FOR [RECEIPTDATEREQUESTED]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_RECEIPTEMAIL]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [RECEIPTEMAIL]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_RECEIPTID]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [RECEIPTID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_REFUNDRECEIPTID]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [REFUNDRECEIPTID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_REPLICATED]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [REPLICATED]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_RETRIEVEDFROMRECEIPTID]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [RETRIEVEDFROMRECEIPTID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_ROUNDEDAMOUNT]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [ROUNDEDAMOUNT]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_SALEISRETURNSALE]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [SALEISRETURNSALE]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_SALESINVOICEAMOUNT]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [SALESINVOICEAMOUNT]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_SALESORDERAMOUNT]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [SALESORDERAMOUNT]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_SALESORDERID]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [SALESORDERID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_SALESPAYMENTDIFFERENCE]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [SALESPAYMENTDIFFERENCE]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_SHIFT]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [SHIFT]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_SHIFTDATE]  DEFAULT ('1900-01-01') FOR [SHIFTDATE]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_SHIPPINGDATEREQUESTED]  DEFAULT ('1900-01-01') FOR [SHIPPINGDATEREQUESTED]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_SKIPAGGREGATION]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [SKIPAGGREGATION]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_STAFF]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [STAFF]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_STATEMENTCODE]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [STATEMENTCODE]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_STORE]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [STORE]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_TERMINAL]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [TERMINAL]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_TIMEWHENTOTALPRESSED]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [TIMEWHENTOTALPRESSED]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_TIMEWHENTRANSCLOSED]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [TIMEWHENTRANSCLOSED]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_TOACCOUNT]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [TOACCOUNT]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_TOTALDISCAMOUNT]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [TOTALDISCAMOUNT]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_TOTALMANUALDISCOUNTAMOUNT]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [TOTALMANUALDISCOUNTAMOUNT]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_TOTALMANUALDISCOUNTPERCENTAGE]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [TOTALMANUALDISCOUNTPERCENTAGE]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_TRANSACTIONID]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [TRANSACTIONID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_TRANSCODE]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [TRANSCODE]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_TRANSDATE]  DEFAULT ('1900-01-01') FOR [TRANSDATE]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_TRANSTABLEID]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [TRANSTABLEID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_TRANSTIME]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [TRANSTIME]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_TYPE]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [TYPE]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_WRONGSHIFT]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [WRONGSHIFT]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_CREATEDDATETIME]  DEFAULT (getutcdate()) FOR [CREATEDDATETIME]
GO

ALTER TABLE [ax].[RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE_MODIFIEDDATETIME]  DEFAULT (getutcdate()) FOR [MODIFIEDDATETIME]
GO
```

It's running on SQL Server.

Clarifications (see the chat room for more discussion):

> - It needs to update all rows which are `"type" = 2`.
> - We basically only need to update the `"TransactionID"` pk column. Here is an example: `'Store1-Terminal2-3'`. The `'Store1-Terminal2'` will be the same for all rows, so it's basically only increasing the number at the end.
> - The pattern of all `TransactionID` values is: `'StoreXX-TerminalYY-ZZZ'` where `ZZZ` is (only digits) an integer and there are exactly two dashes: `-` separating the three parts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49651/discussion-between-minihessel-and-ypercube).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the assumptions:

> - It needs to update all rows which are `"type" = 2`.
> - We basically only need to update the `"TransactionID"` pk column. Here is an example: `'Store1-Terminal2-3'`. The `'Store1-Terminal2'` will be the same for all rows, so it's basically only increasing the number at the end.
> - The pattern of all `TransactionID` values is: `'StoreXX-TerminalYY-ZZZ'` where `ZZZ` is (only digits) an integer and there are exactly two dashes: `-` separating the three parts.

We could first manipulate the `TransactionID` strings (find the last part, convert it integer, add the fixed start_value, etc)):

```
DECLARE @startvalue INT ;
SET @startvalue = 500 ;

SELECT TransactionID,
       num = CAST(last_part AS INT),
       rn  = @startvalue - 1 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                                 (ORDER BY CAST(last_part AS INT)),
       NewTransactionID 
         = b.first_part 
           + CAST(@startvalue - 1 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                                      (ORDER BY CAST(last_part AS INT))
                  AS NVARCHAR(10))
FROM RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE AS t
  CROSS APPLY
    ( SELECT 1 + LEN(TransactionID) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(TransactionID))
    ) AS a (first_part_length)
  CROSS APPLY
    ( SELECT SUBSTRING(TransactionID, 1,
                                       a.first_part_length),
             SUBSTRING(TransactionID, 1 + a.first_part_length,  
                                       LEN(TransactionID))
    ) AS b (first_part, last_part)
WHERE t.Type = 2 ;
```

Once we are satisfied with the results, we can then convert the above to an `UPDATE` statement:

```
DECLARE @startvalue INT ;
SET @startvalue = 500 ;

WITH upd AS
    (
    SELECT TransactionID,
           NewTransactionID 
              = b.first_part 
                + CAST(@startvalue -1 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                                          (ORDER BY CAST(last_part AS INT)) 
                       AS NVARCHAR(10))
    FROM RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE AS t
      CROSS APPLY
        ( SELECT 1 + LEN(TransactionID) - CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(TransactionID))
        ) AS a (first_part_length)
      CROSS APPLY
        ( SELECT SUBSTRING(TransactionID, 1,
                                          a.first_part_length),
                 SUBSTRING(TransactionID, 1 + a.first_part_length,  
                                          LEN(TransactionID))
        ) AS b (first_part, last_part)
    WHERE t.Type = 2
    )  
UPDATE upd
SET TransactionID = NewTransactionID ;
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading the question right, you could use a combination of a few variables, a `cte`, and the `row_number()` function to write this type statement. You can add more conditions to the cte to get to the exact data set you are looking for, and drop the `TOP` variable if it isn't helpful.

e.g. rextester: http://rextester.com/OIBEDZ93140
updated: http://rextester.com/TGZR4250

```
if exists (select * from tempdb.sys.objects where name like '#retailtransactiontable%') begin; drop table #retailtransactiontable; end;
create table #retailtransactiontable (
    [store] [nvarchar](10) not null
  , [terminal] [nvarchar](10) not null
  , [type] [int] not null
  , [transactionid] [nvarchar](44) not null);

insert into #retailtransactiontable (store, terminal, [type], transactionid) values
('1','2',1,'Store1-Terminal2-T1'), ('1','2',2,'Store1-Terminal2-1'), ('1','2',2,'Store1-Terminal2-13'), ('1','2',2,'Store1-Terminal2-5'), ('1','2',2,'Store1-Terminal2-7'), ('1','2',2,'Store1-Terminal2-9')

select * from #retailtransactiontable;

declare @FirstTransactionIdToUpdate int = 5;
declare @NewTransactionIdStart      int = 2;

with cte as (
   select 
        store
      , terminal
      , type
      , transactionid
      , transint = convert(int,(right(transactionid,charindex('-',reverse(transactionid))-1)))
      , newtransactionid = 'Store'+convert(nvarchar(10),Store)
                         + '-Terminal'+convert(nvarchar(22),Terminal)
                         +'-'+convert(nvarchar(3)
                            ,((@NewTransactionIdStart+(row_number() over (order by transactionid))-1)))
      --, newid = (@NewTransactionIdStart+(row_number() over (order by transactionid))-1)
      from #retailtransactiontable
      where store='1'
        and terminal='2'
        and [type]=2
        and convert(int,(right(transactionid,charindex('-',reverse(transactionid))-1))) >= @FirstTransactionIdToUpdate
    )
    --select * from cte
    update cte set transactionid = newtransactionid;

select * from #retailtransactiontable;
```

before:

```
store      terminal   type        transactionid
---------- ---------- ----------- --------------------------------------------
1          2          1           Store1-Terminal2-T1
1          2          2           Store1-Terminal2-1
1          2          2           Store1-Terminal2-13
1          2          2           Store1-Terminal2-5
1          2          2           Store1-Terminal2-7
1          2          2           Store1-Terminal2-9
```

after:

```
store      terminal   type        transactionid
---------- ---------- ----------- --------------------------------------------
1          2          1           Store1-Terminal2-T1
1          2          2           Store1-Terminal2-1
1          2          2           Store1-Terminal2-2
1          2          2           Store1-Terminal2-3
1          2          2           Store1-Terminal2-4
1          2          2           Store1-Terminal2-5
```